# Convert mtw minitab files to readable mtp files

Tags: r, minitab

I have been given a minitab worksheet file (.mtw), and I would like to open it in R.

Unfortunately, I only know of R's foreign package to open other filetypes, which only includes minitab's portable files (.mtp). Is there a way to open .mtw files, and if not how would I go about converting the file to .mtp?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your `mtw` worksheet to `mtp` extension, simply open the `mtw` file on minitab and from File menu select "Save Current Worksheet As" and save it to `mtp` extension. It will save it as Text not Encrypted

You would be able then to use `foreign`